# For $f: X\to Y:=\operatorname{Spec}A$, $X_{\varphi(s)} = f^{-1}(D(s))$, where $\varphi := f^{\flat}_Y$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f :X \to Y := \operatorname{Spec}A$ and $\varphi := f^{\flat}_Y : A \to \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ the induced homomorphism, possibly injective. $X$ can be quasi-compact.

Let $s \in A$.

Let $X_{\varphi(s)}:=\{x\in X : \varphi(s)_x \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\times} \} $ and $D(s) := \{
 \mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}A : s\notin \mathfrak{p} \}$.

Then my question is, $X_{\varphi(s)}=f^{-1}(D(s))$ ? If not, when?

I don't know where to approach it. What notice makes proof possible? What will be key points?

Comment: Start with the case when $X$ and $Y$ are both affine. Then you can more easily formulate what it is you're trying to do and just do ring theory rather than worry about points on a scheme, interpreting them as prime ideals etc..

Comment: Uhm..Can I ask more? We may assume that $X$ is affine? Then why? Anyway, I'll try to it and will ask again after trial, if you have time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in X$. The associated local ring homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ sends units to units and non-units to non-units. Therefore $\varphi (s)_x \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^*$ is equivalent to $f(x)\in D(s)$.

Comment: Your answer seems to be somewhat suggestive. Can you explain more in detail?

Comment: OK. Every ring homomorphism $f$ sends a unit $u$ to unit, which can be seen by applying $f$ to $ut=1$. The non-units consists the maximal ideal in a local ring, and by definition of a local ring homomorphism, it sends non-units to non-units. The third sentence is simply some set-theory.

Comment: O.K. I understand your comment. Thanks. And how about next? I'm struggling with showing the equivalence and I don't know what is key point to show the equivalence. Why is it true?. Anyway I'll try to prove it. Please understand my speed of understanding. :)

Comment: $x\in X_{\varphi (s)} \iff \varphi (s)_x \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}^* \iff s \in  \mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}^*$ (here we use the unit-to-unit argument) $\iff s \in A\setminus \mathfrak{p}_{f(x)} \iff s \notin \mathfrak{p}_{f(x)} \iff f(x)\in D(s) \iff x \in f^{-1}(D(s)) $. Sorry for the lack of explanation. This is almost the first time I use latex and I am struggling with it.

Comment: It's okay!  Uhm.. I don't understand the second and thrid equaivalence. A point that makes me confusing is, $s$ is an element of $A$ but $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}^{\times} = (A_{\mathfrak{p}_{f(x)}})^{\times}$. So, the statement $s\in \mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}^{\times}$ is nonsense?

Comment: It is my fault. I intended $s_{f(x)} \in \mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}^*$.

Comment: Wow, one of key point is $f^{\sharp}_x (s_{f(x)})=\varphi(s)_x$. I'm now trying to prove the third equivalence. Upto the isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}^{\times} \cong A_{\mathfrak{p}_{f(x)}}^{\times}$, where will  $s_{f(x)} := [(Y,s)]_{f(x)}$ go? I knew about this issue but now I forgot~ (Final question is, why the third equivalence ts true? )

Comment: In fact, we can see the equality  $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}=A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$ as inductive limits. The object $ A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$ and the morphisms $A_f \to A_{\mathfrak{p}_y}$ induced by the universal property of localization holds the universal property of inductive limit of the inductive system $\{A_f\mid x\in D(f) \subset Y\}$. Thus we can think of $s_{f(x)}$ as already in $A_{\mathfrak{p}_{f(x)}}$.

Comment: So, $s_{f(x)}$ is the image of $s$ by the canonical morphism $A \to A_{\mathfrak{p}_{f(x)}}$. The maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}$ corresponds $\mathfrak{p}_{f(x)} A_{\mathfrak{p}_{f(x)}} \subset A_{\mathfrak{p}_{f(x)}}$, and the third equivalence holds.

Comment: O.K. Altough I don't understand completely why $s_{f(x)}$ is $s/1$ now (I'll check it, directly ), I understand the third equivalence. Thanks for kind explanation !~